# How to disable ASP.NET render default html tag?

Tags: asp.net

For some reason, i have to make a aspx page to let iphone/android to Post form.
After the data processing of request.form ,  i have response a JSON string in plain text.
However *.aspx will enforce to render html,head,body tag,so how can i disable it?

I cannot use ashx, because the mobile have to post image via form, as i search the answer by google ,ashx cannot handle the http post files.

**Edit:
As SLaks said, ashx can handle POST file using "context.Request.Files" and it works.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are wrong.

ASHX files can handle HTTP POSTs.

To answer the question, you can delete all of the content in the ASPX file.  ASPX files do not *need* to have any content at all (other than the `<%@ Page %>` directive)

Comment: Yes.  Look at `context.Request.Files`.

Answer (score 3):

When processing the post, use this code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/json";

Response.Write("your json goes here");

Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `Response`, set the content-type since it's json, add your json then end it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    Response.Write("your json");
    Response.End();
}
```

Outputs exactly

```
your json
```